# How to use .getBounds() function with the following code?

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I have the following code and I am trying to only display items under the map that actually show on the map for example if I zoom into 1 of the locations and the other location is not shown on the map anymore not to show it on the list below the map.
Is it possible to do with the code I currently have?

Thank you in advance.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var map;
var markers = [];
var lastinfowindow;
var locIndex;

if ( !Array.prototype.forEach ) {
  Array.prototype.forEach = function(fn, scope) {
    for(var i = 0, len = this.length; i < len; ++i) {
      fn.call(scope, this[i], i, this);
    }
  }
}

var data = [
{address:'London Bridge Railway Station Tooley Street London SE1 2SW',title:'Address 1',type:''},
{address:'12 Millbank London SW1P 4QE',title:'Address 2',type:'work'}
];

function getIcon(type) {
    switch(type) {
        case "pharmacy": return "icons/drugstore.png";
        case "hospital": return "icons/hospital-building.png";
        case "work": return "icons/work.png";
        default: return "icons/footprint.png";
    }
}

function initialize() {
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(51.149087, 0.436707);
    var myOptions = {
        zoom: 8,
        center: latlng,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),myOptions);

    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

    data.forEach(function(mapData,idx) {
        geocoder.geocode( { 'address': mapData.address}, function(results, status) {
                if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                        map: map, 
                        position: results[0].geometry.location,
                        title: mapData.title,
                        icon: getIcon(mapData.type)
                    });
                    var contentHtml = "<div style='width:300px;height:200px'><h3>"+mapData.title+"</h3>"+mapData.address+"</div>";
                    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                        content: contentHtml
                    });
                    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
                      infowindow.open(map,marker);
                    });
                    marker.locid = idx+1;
                    marker.infowindow = infowindow;
                    markers[markers.length] = marker;

                    var sideHtml = '<p class="loc" data-locid="'+marker.locid+'"><b>'+mapData.title+'</b><br/>';
                         sideHtml += mapData.address + '</p>';
                         $("#locs").append(sideHtml); 

                }
            });

    });

    $(document).on("click",".loc",function() {
        var thisloc = $(this).data("locid");
        for(var i=0; i<markers.length; i++) {
            if(markers[i].locid == thisloc) {
                if(lastinfowindow instanceof google.maps.InfoWindow) lastinfowindow.close();
                map.panTo(markers[i].getPosition());
                markers[i].infowindow.open(map, markers[i]);
                lastinfowindow = markers[i].infowindow;
            }
        }
    });

}
</script>
<style>
#map_canvas { 
    width: 100%; height: 400px; 
}
#locs {
    margin-top: 0px;
    padding-top: 0px;
    height: auto;
}
#locs p {
    float:left;
    margin:5px;
}
.loc {
    border-style:solid;    
    border-width:thin; 
    width: 300px;
    padding: 5px;  
    cursor:pointer; 
    margin-top:0px;
}
label {
    width: 200px;
    padding: 5px;  
}

</style>
</head>
<body onLoad="initialize()">

<div id="map_canvas"></div>

<div id="locs"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could get the [`LatLngBounds`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#LatLngBounds) from your Map object and then check if your other point(s) are contained in the bounds.

So in your `click`handler:

```
// Get the LatLngBounds object
var latlngbounds = map.getBounds();

// loop through the markers
for(var i=0, j=markers.length; i<j; i++) {

    // check if marker is contained in bounds
    if(!latlngbounds.contains(markers[i].getPosition())) {

         // if not, remove from map
         markers[i].setMap(null);
    }
}
```

Comment: I get an error  with your code on the following line if(!latlngbounds.contains(markers[i].position) { where abouts would I add this? I have 2 click handlers in this script?

Comment: My mistake, i think you need to call `getPosition` on the marker object.

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer. This is still kicking back an invalid code error, where should this code belong within the rest of the JS?

Comment: As I don't know the rest of your code, only the part you have shown above, I would put this in your click handler.
You will probably need to loop through your markers twice. So put it after your first `for`loop.

Comment: Oh, I misread your original questions. You don't care about the marker but the infotext below the map :-)
So please forget everything and bind to the `boundschanged` event of your map. Inside that handler you have to check your markers and discard the addresses that are not currently visible on the map.

Comment: Would you be able to give an example? Sorry I'm not great with JS.

Comment: Perfect, thank you. If you put it as an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: getting error "TypeError: latlngbounds is undefined" while i have already defined as you suggested.